# Slurm job arrays with Stata

Tags: stata, slurm

I want to run some Stata code in parallel using slurm job arrays.

I know that I can run 100 jobs doing:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --array=1-100

module load stata
stata my_code.do $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID
```

Now each code will have to read a file that takes the slurm_array_task_id.

I.e. inside the `my_code.do` there is an instruction that makes:

```
use "my_data.dta" in `j', clear
```

where `j' is the slurm array task id.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the first argument passed to your do-file with `` `1' ``. So I think in your code example you could just put:

```
use "my_data.dta" in `1', clear
```

More info [here](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/programming/passing-arguments-to-do-files/).